# Checking firebug changes

Tags: css, firefox, firebug

So I see a webpage. Make some changes with CSS.  Make a few more.  And then make a few more.  I'd love to be able to get a delta that would tell me everything I have changed.

Is this possible?

Comment: Where are you making the changes? In firebug or in your files? Do you use SVN or GIT?

Comment: @mtashev I am making them in Firebug

Comment: Chrome Inspector can do this natively, without plugins: http://devcoma.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/change-css-and-save-on-local-file.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [FireFile](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#FireFile) extension for firebug.
You can monitor your changes and save directly if you wish.

Additional info: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefile/

Another option is [cssUpdater](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#cssUpdater)